# Slow File Download from Google Cloud Storage while Using Pub/Sub Subscription in Python

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, python-multithreading, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on a Python script that subscribes to a Google Cloud Pub/Sub topic, and upon receiving a message, it triggers the download of files from a Google Cloud Storage bucket. The code is structured using threading and a queue to manage the processing of messages and the subsequent file download tasks. Below is the essential part of my script:

```
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1, storage
import os, queue, threading

# Setting up authentication
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'key-path'

# Initializing Pub/Sub subscriber
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path('project-name', 'subscription-name')

# Setting up a task queue
task_queue = queue.Queue()

def download_folder(bucket_name, source_folder_name, destination_folder_path):
    # Initiating GCS client and fetching the blobs
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=f"{source_folder_name}/")
    print("Authorization DONE")
    for blob in blobs:
        if blob.name.endswith('/'):
            continue  # Skipping directories
        print("FIRST FILE DOWNLOADING")
        # Ensuring the destination directory exists
        os.makedirs(destination_folder_path, exist_ok=True)
        destination_file = f"{destination_folder_path}/{blob.name.split('/')[-1]}"
        print(destination_file)
        # Downloading the blob to a file
        blob.download_to_filename(destination_file)
        print(f"Downloaded {blob.name}")
    
def process_task(message_list):
    print("Start downloading media files....")
    source_folder_name = message_list[0]
    destination_folder_path = f'D:/{source_folder_name}'
    print(source_folder_name)
    print(destination_folder_path)
    # Triggering the download function
    download_folder("bucket-name", source_folder_name, destination_folder_path)
    print(f'Processed task with data: {message_list}')
    
def task_manager():
    while True:
        next_task_data = task_queue.get()
        process_task(next_task_data)

def callback(message):
    print(f'Received new message')
    message_string = message.data.decode('utf-8')
    message_list = message_string.split(',')
    print(message_string)
    # Adding the message data to the task queue
    task_queue.put(message_list)
    message.ack()
    task_manager()

# Starting the task manager in a separate thread
processor_thread = threading.Thread(target=task_manager)
processor_thread.start()
# Subscribing to the Pub/Sub topic
subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=callback)

try:
    print('Listening for messages...')
    while True:
        pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

I am facing a perplexing issue with this setup. When I manually call the download_folder and process_task functions, the files get downloaded from the GCS bucket swiftly within a second. However, when I run the script with threading and queue as shown above, the file downloads are significantly slower, taking up to 15 minutes.

I initially thought the threading or queue might be causing the slowdown, but upon further investigation, it seems like the Pub/Sub subscription might be the culprit. When the Pub/Sub subscription is active, the file downloads are slow, but if I comment out the subscriber.subscribe(...) line and manually trigger the process_task function, the downloads are fast again.

I am trying to understand why the Pub/Sub subscription is affecting the file download speed from GCS, and how I might be able to resolve this issue to ensure fast file downloads while still using the Pub/Sub subscription for triggering the downloads.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to turn off the threading parts?

Comment: Yep, even when I turned off threading and queue parts, download is slow. When I turn off subscription and leave threading and queue, the download is fast

Comment: Your `while True:` loop wastes processor resources and can cause your app to lock up. Add a `time.sleep(1)` call to test.

Comment: Thanks a lot, John. It works. Should I change this construction to be more correctly or leave it like this?

try:
    print('Listening for messages...')
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

Comment: Are you terminating the program with CTRL-C? If yes, sleep for a long time such as 60 seconds. Note: your program needs exception handling or else it will crash on some errors.